# Custom font not showing on device

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to add a custom font following the "Fonts in XML" tutorial on this [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html). I followed the tutorial to the letter and checked many times to find something I missed but I just can't see it. The font I added is a TTF file.

In the designer, I can select my font family and the text in the TextView changes to the custom font I added. However, when I run the app on my device, the text is defaulted to the regular font. This doesn't happen with the fonts included in Android Studio.

Additional question: when I tried yet another custom font, the text in the TextView changed to the custom font, but the text itself (the content) also changed to some gibberish. Is this an indication of a bad font or something else?

sv_regular.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/sv_font_regular" />

</font-family>
```

TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sv_regular"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Could you post some code of what you tried, so we don't guess but actually work on the concrete issue? Btw, as an android engineer, i do not think that tutorial is the best way to tackle custom fonts in an android application.

Comment: The code is literally copy-paste from the tutorial, except the font name, that's why I didn't post it. What would you recommend for implementing custom fonts?

Comment: for your second question maybe the content isn't supported by the font.

Comment: Also, have you tried changing the font?

Comment: I would suggest something similar to what Kishan Verna suggested...
Basically, what I always do for these "custom fonts" things is the following:
1) make a `CustomTextView extends TextView`
2) make a `"fontStyle"` custom attribute
3) put the custom fonts in the `assets/` folder
4) make a `FontManager` class that works with the custom fonts
5) make the `CustomTextView` constructor apply the custom font in it's constructor.
6) Use `CustomTextView` instead of `TextView` in all XMLs

Comment: @Shark Could you explain why your method (extending `TextView`) is 'better' than simply adding a custom font file (`@font/myfont`)? Seems like more work for the app for no gain. But I know little on this subject. Is it better for the system in some way or is it simply a personal preference, being an Android engineer.

Comment: I will, briefly; font support has improved in the previous couple of versions of the SDK, but has been terrible way back. When customers/client want to use a non-standard (but usually same) font for all their textviews, the suggested approach was the quickest way of addressing all of them in a identical way. Later on, when the font is changed, you just change it in the custom class. But it's best to make it parametrized via XML with a custom attribute... You can use libraries that support the `fontFamily` approach; e.g. Caligraphy.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this programmatically**

**Add external fonts in your assets folder**

**1. Go to the (project folder)**

**2. Then app>src>main**

**3. Create folder 'assets>fonts' into the main folder.**

**4. Put your 'abc.ttf' into the fonts folder.**

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/abc.ttf");

tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such a problem when the font is displayed in Android Studio but does not work on a physical device.

So if you want a custom font from Android Studio to be displayed on your phone screen, you need to add this font to your project as follows:

1. Open res folder.
2. Create Android Resource Directory. Resource type - font. You can also name your new folder *font*.
3. Then simply drag and drop your ttf font into the font folder. Important: The font name must not contain prohibited characters, and all letters in the name must be lowercase. The name of my font in this example: *kopenhagen*
   (you may have a different font name).
4. Open your xml file, find the text in which you want to change the font, and just add the following:
   android:fontFamily="@font/*kopenhagen*"

*Instead of the word *kopenhagen*, use the name of your font

Answer (score -1):

Does your font exactly support the language of the text? This problem occurs when the font does not support certain characters, such as Cyrillic. And one more: try use `sv_font_regular` in `TextView`

> android:fontFamily="@font/sv_font_regular"

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCLnw.png)

Comment: As I said, in the Android Studio designer the content of my TextView is written in the custom font, without error. No Cyrillic or anything similar since I don't use it. I didn't use big characters in the font name (I even deleted the underscore now just to be certain, but still nothing).